# How to include relative urls using ssl

Tags: .htaccess, url, ssl

I want to know how could I include urls like "/images/image.png" but with SSL so the browser doesn't say "This page includes non secure resources"

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a relative path and the document itself was requested via HTTPS, then the browser will automatically request those images via HTTPS too. So I don’t see what your problem actually is here …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^images/.+?\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense unless it counteracts a global `https://` to `http://` redirection somewhere else in the configuration. Otherwise, this rewrite condition forces plain `http://` requests to be redirected to `https://` for these images. Unfortunately, this would also imply that the browser has already made a plain `http://` request, which would already cause a mixed-content warning.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're viewing a page using `https://`, the relative links will also use `https://`.
2. Make sure you serve these images on your server with its HTTPS configuration. Try to go directly to the address of these resources using their `https://`: it's possible that your server may be configured differently for its HTTP and HTTPS virtualhosts (in Apache Http terminology, this could be different for another server).
3. If your server has an automatic redirection for these images from `https://` to `http://`, remove it: you don't want there to be any redirection at all.

   In addition, rewrite rules from `https://` to `http://` are often seen as a way to save CPU resources for content for which HTTPS isn't required. I doubt this is really worth it in practice, since the main overhead of HTTPS is in the handshake, which will have been performed to get the redirection itself anyway.